# How do i handle PeerJS web RTC with live video stream server?

Tags: node.js, rtmp, peerjs

Good day fellow developers,
Recently i just developed web RTC using PeerJS, it works correctly no problem, until i handle 5+ clients, the internet on the devices are just giving up, they can't. And this one is what i just discovered on the documentation page:

> Data sent between the two peers do not touch any other servers, so the connection speed is limited only by the upload and download rates of the two peers. This also means you don't have the additional latency of an intermediary server.

Which is why the client devices are giving up, how do i make livestream server that handle peerjs? i've googled and i only found the live stream server for OBS, i want the server to handle PeerJS WebRTC like BigBlueButton.
Thanks in advance